# My probability program is returning different results when I run the code on different IDES

Tags: python, random

I have a program that takes a number of colored balls and puts them into a hat.

I then pick N amounts of balls to be drawn out of the hat X amounts of times.

I have a specific combination of colored balls that I am testing for(expected_balls).
for example: {'blue': 2, 'green': 3}

**This is the code i'm using to get the probability:**

```
def experiment(hat, expected_balls, num_balls_drawn, num_experiments):
    matches = 0

    for experiment in range(num_experiments):
        result = hat.draw(num_balls_drawn)
        result = Counter(result)
        chk = True

        for k, v in expected_balls.items():
            if result[k] < v:
                chk = False
                break

        if chk:
            matches += 1

return (matches/num_experiments)
```

**to get the result from drawing out of the hat I'm using:**

```
def draw(self, n):
    drawn = []

    for r in range(n):
        b = random.choice(self.contents)
        self.contents.remove(b)
        drawn.append(b)
        if len(self.contents) == 0:
            self.contents = copy.deepcopy(self.contents_copy)
    return(drawn)
```

This code is for a project for class.
I wrote the code on Atom and the answer probability matches what the project is looking for.
However when I run it on replit, where I submit the project the answer comes out totally different.

Why is the answer different when I run it on two different programs.

Comment: where is `random` used here ?

Comment: What are the different results you are getting?

Comment: Your code may be relying on hash table insertion order, but that order is randomized in Python.  But it's hard to tell for sure unless you include all the code that reproduces your problem (for example, what is the code for `Counter` and `hat.draw()`.

Comment: @ping.shantanu The random is in another class that is being called in "hat.draw(num_balls_drawn)" Also, I'm using random.choice() if that clarifies anything.

Comment: @PeterO. I added in the hat.draw() section of the code and the Counter is from the collections library

Comment: @IainShelvington In Atom I'm getting 0.276, in replit I'm getting 0.57

Comment: For probability, you need to do more than 1 times. Do it 100 times and average out the result. If the code is same, on average of 100 times, the result will be more or less the same. This is how probabilistic nature of solution works.

Comment: @bradley101 the num_experiments argument in the experiments function is the amount of times the experiment was run. In my case it was run 1000 times.

Comment: call `random.seed(0)`, or any other [seed value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed) to make your the returns of `random.choice` the same. Call it before any for loop, e.g. before `def experiment`

Comment: Please read the help section on how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).